# Accepting input using Haskell

Tags: haskell, input

I have to read input as:

```
1 <- number of lines next
10 20 30
2 <- number of lines next
5 5 5
6 8 9
0 <- terminating condition
```

The output should be:

```
output of f[(10,20,30)]
output of f[(5,5,5),(6,8,9)]
```

I also need to print the case number:

eg.

```
Case 1: ...
Case 2: ...
```

The function which produces the output has type:
`f :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> Int`

I am using it as:

```
loop = do
 x <- getLine
 if x == "0"
  then return ()
  else do arr <- replicateM (read x :: Int) getLine 
          let queries = map (read :: String -> Int) $ words $ unwords arr
          print $ f $ pairUp queries;
          loop

main = loop

pairUp :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int,Int)]
pairUp (0:0:0:_) = []
pairUp (n:m:o:rest) = (n,m,o) : (pairUp rest)
pairUp (_) = []
```

**This prints immediately after one test case but continues till 0**

Is there any way I can print the output at the end?

Comment: Your logic is just inside-out. You should be checking for the terminator in `main` not `readData`.

Comment: @ReidBarton, but then how should I pass `n` lines to my function??

Comment: Not sure this question deserves two question marks. You already have the pieces `replicateM (head val)` and `fmap (map read . words) getLine` that you need.

Comment: @ReidBarton, please take a look at my edit

Comment: Should output only display after the terminating condition?

Comment: @mnoronha, Yes it must

Comment: And the print order matters?

Comment: @mnoronha, thanks for your interest in helping me out. I have posted another edit in which I have made several adjustments. Yes, the order matters

Comment: @mnoronha, can you help me out with printing the case number as described in the question. And any luck on printing the output at the end? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Print case number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901651/haskell-print-case-number)