# Haskell: Print case number

Tags: haskell

I have written a Haskell code as:

```
loop = do
 x <- getLine
 if x == "0"
  then return ()
  else do arr <- replicateM (read x :: Int) getLine 
          let blocks = map (read :: String -> Int) $ words $ unwords arr
          putStr "Case X : output = "; -- <- What should X be?
          print $ solve $ blockPair blocks;
          loop

main = loop
```

This terminates at 0 input. I also want to print the case number eg. `Case 1, 2 ...`

Sample run:

```
1
10 20 30
Case 1: Output = ...
1
6 8 10
Case 2: Output = ...
0
```

Does anyone know how this can be done? Also, If possible can you suggest me a way to print the output line at the very end?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Also, If possible can you suggest me a way to print the output line at the very end?" -- I'm not sure about what else you would like to print, and at which point it should happen..

Comment: @duplode, it should run like - all inputs at the beginning and then after the user inputs a 0, it should print the outputs.

Comment: I need some help please

Comment: Randomly... did you know that your type signatures on `read` are unnecessary?  You can just say e.g. `replicateM (read x) getLine.  Type inference will figure out what type you are trying to read.  (It felt like magic the first time I did this)

Comment: @luqui. Thanks for the wonderful hint. I am just a beginner in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question, the current case number is an example of some "state" that you want to maintain during the course of your program's execution.  In other languages, you'd use a mutable variable, no doubt.

In Haskell, there are several ways to deal with state.  One of the simplest (though it is sometimes a little ugly) is to pass the state explicitly as a function parameter, and this will work pretty well given the way you've already structured your code:

```
main = loop 1

loop n = do
  ...
  putStr ("Case " ++ show n ++ ": Output = ...")
  ...
  loop (n+1)  -- update "state" for next loop
```

The second part of your question is a little more involved.  It looks like you wanted a hint instead of a solution.  To get you started, let me show you an example of a function that reads lines until the user enters `end` and then returns the list of all the lines up to but not including `end` (together with a `main` function that does something interesting with the lines using mostly pure code):

```
readToEnd :: IO [String]
readToEnd = do
    line <- getLine
    if line == "end"
      then return []
    else do
      rest <- readToEnd
      return (line:rest)

main = do
    lines <- readToEnd
    -- now "pure" code makes complex manipulations easy:
    putStr $ unlines $
      zipWith (\n line -> "Case " ++ show n ++ ": " ++ line)
              [1..] lines
```

Edit:  I guess you wanted a more direct answer instead of a hint, so the way you would adapt the above approach to reading a list of blocks would be to write something like:

```
readBlocks :: IO [[Int]]
readBlocks = do
  n <- read <$> getLine
  if n == 0 then return [] else do
    arr <- replicateM n getLine
    let block = map read $ words $ unwords arr
    blocks <- readBlocks
    return (block:blocks)
```

and then `main` would look like this:

```
main = do
  blocks <- readBlocks
  putStr $ unlines $
    zipWith (\n line -> "Case " ++ show n ++ ": " ++ line)
          [1..] (map (show . solve . blockPair) blocks)
```

Comment: Thanks, your first trick worked. But regarding the second, I have a similar function that terminates on 0 input, but how can I control the parameters getting passed to my output function? Your code will process each line as a separate parameter, which is not what I want. Anyways, thanks for trying.

Comment: Yes, now your approach is more clearer. That's exactly what I want. I guess the problem is now solved. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user7201762, if this answer did the trick, you can mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking the check mark at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar in spirit to K. A. Buhr's answer (the crucial move is still passing state as a parameter), but factored differently to demonstrate a neat trick. Since `IO` actions are just normal Haskell values, you can use the loop to build the action which will print the output without executing it:

```
loop :: (Int, IO ()) -> IO ()
loop (nCase, prnAccum) = do
 x <- getLine
 if x == "0"
  then prnAccum
  else do inpLines <- replicateM (read x) getLine 
          let blocks = map read $ words $ unwords inpLines
              prnAccumAndNext = do
                  prnAccum
                  putStr $ "Case " ++ show nCase ++ " : output = "
                  print $ solve $ blockPair blocks
          loop (nCase + 1, prnAccumAndNext)

main = loop (1, return ())
```

Some remarks on the solution above:

- `prnAccum`, the action which prints the results, is threaded through the recursive loop calls just like `nCase` (I packaged them both in a pair as a matter of style, but it would have worked just as fine if they were passed as separate arguments).
- Note how the updated action, `prnAccumAndNext`, is not directly in the main `do` block; it is defined in a `let` block instead. That explains why it is not executed on each iteration, but only at the end of the loop, when the final `prnAccum` is executed.
- As luqui suggests, I have removed the type annotations you used with `read`. The one at the `replicateM` call is certainly not necessary, and the other one isn't as well as long as `blockPair` takes a list of `Int` as an argument, as it seems to be the case.
- Nitpicking: I removed the semicolons, as they are not necessary. Also, if `arr` refers to "array" it isn't a very appropriate name (as it is a list, and not an array), so I took the liberty to change it into something more descriptive. (You can find some other ideas for useful tricks and style adjustments in K. A. Buhr's answer.)